# Ajax Post Request in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am currently trying to build an HTML5 Chrome Extension application but I am having problems sending a post request to the api I am using. I am trying to perform an ajax post request on my content.js file but I received an Uncaught Reference: $ not defined error every time I run it. To solve it, I have to import the jquery library but I don't know how to do it within a javascript file. Any ideas on how to solve it.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Etude",
    "description":"Etude's Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Jon Saad-Falcon",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Etude_Logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default title": "Etude"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false,
  }
}
```

Here is my content.js

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("text", "text to summarize");

var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.deepai.org/api/summarization",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
        "Api-Key": "my api key",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.16.3",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "590b05f5-6861-4bfb-9f10-76f97ae0d7b0,e86215a3-e4b7-4271-ac5d-ef770cd59b57",
        "Host": "api.deepai.org",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------654208491089543898974720",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Length": "2568",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Use a standard `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. Or put jquery.js in your extension files and declare it in the ”js” array in manifest.json.

Comment: I tried declaring jquery.js in my js array in manifest.json but it still gives the same error. Any idea @wOxxOm

Comment: It should be listed before content.js. Also you need to reload both the extension and the web page.